# Referencing variable in declarative jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using the groovy below to call a bat command, that no matter how i reference the LOCAL_WORKSPACE within the bat command it does not evaluate it.
What am i missing?

Error

> nuget restore $env.LOCAL_WORKSPACE
>   "Input file does not exist: $env.LOCAL_WORKSPACE"

Script

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Clone repo') {
        steps {
            deleteDir()
            git branch: 'myBranch', changelog: false, credentialsId: 'myCreds', poll: false, url: 'http://myRepoURL'
        }
    }
    stage ("Set any variables") {
        steps{
            script{
                LOCAL_BUILD_PATH = "$env.WORKSPACE"
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Build It, yes we can') {
        parallel {
            stage("Build one") {
                steps {
                    echo LOCAL_BUILD_PATH
                    bat 'nuget restore %LOCAL_WORKSPACE%'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set variables to share data between stages. Basically each `script` has its own namespace.

What you can do is use an environment directive as described in the [pipeline syntax docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment). Those *constants* are globally available, but they are *constants*, so you cannot change them in any stage.

You can calculate the values though. For example I use an `sh` step to get the current number of commits on master like this:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        COMMITS_ON_MASTER = sh(script: "git rev-list HEAD --count", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }

    stages {

        stage("Print commits") {
            steps {
                echo "There are ${env.COMMITS_ON_MASTER} commits on master"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about non-environment variables? eg def myvar = '' . then later change the value in a script step, and later reference it in an ansiblePlaybook step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables to store and access to/from stages. For example, if you define LOCAL_ENVR as Jenkins parameter, you can manipulate the variable from stages:

```
stage('Stage1') {
       steps {
           script{
                env.LOCAL_ENVR = '2'
           }
       }
    }
    stage('Stage2') {
         steps {
             echo "${env.LOCAL_ENVR}"
         }
    }
```